# married woman loves another married man

Tags: sharia, islamic-philosophy, jannah

I am married but before my marriage, I had a boyfriend. We both had a good relationship and never crossed our limits, never met each other in person. Only spoke over the phone. Unfortunately, my boyfriend's parents did not approve our relationship and he was forced to get married to someone else.

Now we both want to be together in Akhirat. Is this possible? Can I please Allah for this? I am confused. I still sometimes miss my boyfriend. Now I contacted him. He wants to be with me in Akhirat. Please let me know as soon as possible. Can I ask for him to be mine in Akhirat to Allah?

Comment: you can look here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23446/wishing-husband-to-be-only-mine-in-jannah/23447#23447

Comment: and here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28194/2-wives-in-jannah/28197#28197

Answer (score -3):

I would say that treat your current husband as best as possible, and although you still love your previous "boyfriend", pray that you please and respect your current husband (and vice-versa) and that your "boyfriend's" wife is a good woman and treats him well. I would say that there's nothing wrong with wishing to be united with the man you think you love in the afterlife, if you two indeed do go to Jannah, inshallah - but you shouldn't forget to consider other people's feelings, like your parents', his parents', family of your respective spouses, and of course your husband and his wife's as well. Allah knows best, and you should pray for guidance.
 Remember, Allah gave no one a burden they cannot bear. So attempt your best to be content with what you have.